# Is $\mathsf P$ low for every complexity class between itself and $\mathsf{NP}$?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, np, oracle-machines

We know that $\mathsf P$ is low for itself. It's also low for $\mathsf{NP}$, $\mathsf{RP}$, $\mathsf{UP}$ and some other complexity classes that contain $\mathsf P$ and are contained in $\mathsf{NP}$. Does it actually hold $\forall\mathcal C:\mathsf P\subseteq\mathcal C\subseteq\mathsf{NP}$ that $\mathcal C=\mathcal C^{\mathsf P}$?

So far, thinking about a hypothetical situation where $\mathsf P\subseteq \mathsf{DSPACE}(\mathcal O(n))\subseteq\mathsf{NP}$ my intuition is that $\mathsf{DSPACE}(\mathcal O(n))$ machine can actually use $\mathsf P$ oracle as an extra memory storage.

Comment: I don't think $\mathcal{C}^P$ is well-defined, when $\mathcal{C}$ is an arbitrary subset of $NP$.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/71937/755.